# Wordpress page.php not working it's defaulting to index.php

Tags: wordpress

So, I am doing a tutorial but, every time I go into the wp admin and View one of my pages.It doesn't pull my page.php but, my index.php. I am not sure how to fix this or what I am doing wrong.

````
<?php get_header();

 while(have_posts()) {the_post(); ?>
<h1>This is a page not a post</h1>
  <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php }

  get_footer();
?> ```



<?php get_header();

  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <hr>
  <?php }

  get_footer();

?>```
````

Comment: The code towards the bottom is my index.php code

Comment: Is that code inside your `page.php`?